# OpenGL ES 1.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

What is the reason of objects leaving the track the same color as they have when moving in OpenGL ES 1.0 Android on real device? How to fix this problem?

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    start_frame = System.currentTimeMillis();

    float cam_an = mAngle;
    float cue_an = cue_angle;
    if (replay) {
        controller.init_balls_pos(gl);
        replay = false;
    }
    controller.move_objects(gl, cam_an, cue_an);


    if (overlapped)
        overlapped = false;


    end_frame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time_frame = end_frame - start_frame;
    if (time_frame < FrameTime)
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (FrameTime - time_frame));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }


}


public void move_objects(GL10 gl, float angle, float cue_an) {


    float an = angle;
    float cue_angle = cue_an;
    if(computor.isActive&&!motion) {
        computor.strike(computor.callculateVelocity());
    }

    set_cue_angle(cue_angle);

    float light_p[] = {0.0f, 5.0f, -4.0f, 1.0f};
    float light_p1[] = {0.0f, 5.0f, -6.0f, 1.0f};
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

    l1.clear_MVmatrix(gl);
    camera.move(gl, reset, angle);
    l1.set_position(light_p, gl);

    l2.clear_MVmatrix(gl);
    camera.move(gl, reset, angle);
    l2.set_position(light_p1, gl);


    room.clear_MVmatrix(gl);
    camera.move(gl, reset, angle);

    room.move(0.0f, 3.5f, 2.5f, gl);
    room.draw(gl);

    table.clear_MVmatrix(gl);

    camera.move(gl, reset, angle);


    table.draw(gl);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    move_ball(gl, an);


    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, init_cam_ymove, init_cam_zmove);
    gl.glRotatef(init_cam_an, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.1f, cue.get_pos());
    gl.glRotatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    if (cue.makemove)
        cue.make_move();
    if(!computor.isActive)
    cue.draw1(gl);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    reset = false;
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(1.7f, -0.8f, -4.0f);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    button.draw(gl);


    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(-1.5f, 1.2f, -4.0f);
    pan.draw(gl);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(1.5f, 1.2f, -4.0f);
    pan1.draw(gl);
    if (endOfGame) {
        if (gameover) {
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(game_over.pos[0], game_over.pos[1], game_over.pos[2]);

            game_over.draw(gl);
        } else {
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(victory.pos[0], victory.pos[1], victory.pos[2]);

            victory.draw(gl);
        }
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(exit_but.pos[0], exit_but.pos[1], exit_but.pos[2]);
        exit_but.draw(gl);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(replay_but.pos[0], replay_but.pos[1], replay_but.pos[2]);
        replay_but.draw(gl);

    }

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

    if (motion)
        if (vel_zero()) {
            if((ball_hit&&human.isActive)||(!ball_hit&&computor.isActive)) {
                MyGLRenderer.tcue_angle = cue_an;

                reset = true;
            }
            if(!ball_hit) {
                swapPlayersStates();

            }
            else ball_hit=false;

            motion = false;
        }

    int l = balls.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        Log.e("sf:" + i, "" + balls[i].pos2D.x + " " + balls[i].pos2D.y + " " + balls[i].rot_anY);
    gl.glFlush();


}
```

Comment: Do you have more details? Ideally code that demonstrates the problem? Otherwise we're just left to guess. One possibility is that you're missing a `glClear()` call at the start of your draw method.

Comment: Balls leave not big track when rotating them whith moitionEvent

Comment: May be the reason in asincronius  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)